# How do I remove this make error when building i386-jos-elf?

Tags: c, operating-system

I'm on a MacOS and when I try to make the file it throws an out of bounds possibility error is there a way to fix this error? I need it to build an os from the MIT OS class.
Source: https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2009/tools.html

```sh
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I./../include  -DHAVE_bfd_elf32_i386_vec -DHAVE_i386coff_vec -DHAVE_bfd_elf32_little_generic_vec -DHAVE_bfd_elf32_big_generic_vec  -DBINDIR='"/usr/local/bin"'  -W -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Werror -g -O2 -MT elf32-i386.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/elf32-i386.Tpo -c -o elf32-i386.lo elf32-i386.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I./../include -DHAVE_bfd_elf32_i386_vec -DHAVE_i386coff_vec -DHAVE_bfd_elf32_little_generic_vec -DHAVE_bfd_elf32_big_generic_vec -DBINDIR=\"/usr/local/bin\" -W -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Werror -g -O2 -MT elf32-i386.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/elf32-i386.Tpo -c elf32-i386.c -o elf32-i386.o
elf32-i386.c:326:15: error: array index 42 is past the end of the array (which contains 34 elements) [-Werror,-Warray-bounds]
      return &elf_howto_table[R_386_IRELATIVE];
              ^               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
elf32-i386.c:37:1: note: array 'elf_howto_table' declared here
static reloc_howto_type elf_howto_table[]=
^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: https://github.com/asnr/ostep/blob/master/projects/README.md "change the CFLAGS=-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations option to CFLAGS=-Wno-error. Without this, you'll see the following error:"

Comment: So yes, that happens, the solution is to get rid of `-Werror`.